# Formatting displayed data (properly) in console window from

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I am learning to display data from a database from Sql database in a console window, connection is made, the problem is with my displaying data it isn't uniform/neat. Is there a way around this.

code*

```
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("FirstColumn\tSecond Column\t\tThird Column\t\tForth Column\t");
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} \t | {1} \t\t | {2} \t | {3} \t | {4} \t | ",
                            reader[0], reader[1], reader[2], reader[3], reader[4], reader[5]));
                    }
                }
```

[image: Data displayed]

I would like the data to be displayed aligned and neat.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use padding to properly align the output.

Figure out the width you want for each column, then pad the string accordingly:

```
var value = "Sample";

//Desired length
var length = 20;

//Trim strings longer than the desired length
value = (value.Length > length) ? $"{value.Substring(0,20)}..." : value;

//Pad to always have the same length
var paddedValue = value.PadRight(length, ' ');
```

In the example above, `paddedValue` will contain a string with `Sample` at the beginning and 14 additional spaces.

You can read more about String Padding [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/padding).

This is a simple example but it should be clear to you that you can encapsulate this into reusable functions/classes.

Here is a sample implementation using arrays to illustrate. You could create a function that takes care of trimming/padding the string:

```
private static string GetFormattedValue(string value, int maxLength)
{
    //Trim strings longer than the desired length
    var output = (value.Length > maxLength) ? $"{value.Substring(0, 20)}..." : value;
    //Pad to always have the same length
    var paddedValue = output.PadRight(maxLength, ' ');
    return paddedValue;
}
```

Here is some sample definitions and data:

```
var lengths = new[] { 20, 30, 10 }; 
var headers = new[] { "Title", "Description Header that is also too long", "Quantity" };
var values = new[] {"Small text", "Super long text that will not fit", "15" };
```

Using Linq to generate the strings for **both** the headers and the values (headers could be too long as well!):

```
var headerString = string.Join("|", headers.Select((h, i) => GetFormattedValue(h, lengths[i])));
Console.WriteLine(headerString);
var valueString = string.Join("|", values.Select((v, i) => GetFormattedValue(v, lengths[i])));
Console.WriteLine(valueString);
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did not try but this should kinda work. It is padding reader[0] with spaces on the right, for the specified total length.

```
int totalLength = 50;
Console.WriteLine(reader[0].PadRight(totalLength) + String.Format(" \t | {1} \t\t | {2} \t | {3} \t | {4} \t | ", reader[1], reader[2], reader[3], reader[4], reader[5]));
```

Answer (score 0):

As you did tabulations can be used to correctly align your columns. But the alignment will break if the content of a cell is too big, ie the value `second` push the column too far in the example below:

```
C1    | C2
first | a
second    | b
third | b
```

Moreover you don't control how many spaces one tab is. It is a user setting. It can be 2, 4, 8, or anything else.

The other solution is to **use padding in order to control the exact number of characters** (including spaces) of each column. But the same problem arise if one cell content is too big.

Thus a correct solution is to **use padding with ellipsis** like `text-overflow: ellipsis;` for HTML/CSS rendering.

Say all your column width is 10 characters, you'll need to "cut" the cell content value if it is too large, as in the example:

```
C1        | C2
long      | a
verylong  | b
veryvery..| b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code to use a packaged class to display data in the format of 
table.

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = new TablePrinter("Id", "Name", "Age");
        string connectionstring = "connectionstring";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
        connection.Open();
        string sql = "Select * from Student";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql,connection);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            t.AddRow(reader["Id"], reader["Name"], reader["Age"]);
        }

        t.Print();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class TablePrinter
{
    private readonly string[] titles;
    private readonly List<int> lengths;
    private readonly List<string[]> rows = new List<string[]>();

    public TablePrinter(params string[] titles)
    {
        this.titles = titles;
        lengths = titles.Select(t => t.Length).ToList();
    }

    public void AddRow(params object[] row)
    {
        if (row.Length != titles.Length)
        {
            throw new System.Exception($"Added row length [{row.Length}] is not equal to title row length [{titles.Length}]");
        }
        rows.Add(row.Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray());
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.Length; i++)
        {
            if (rows.Last()[i].Length > lengths[i])
            {
                lengths[i] = rows.Last()[i].Length;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        lengths.ForEach(l => System.Console.Write("+-" + new string('-', l) + '-'));
        System.Console.WriteLine("+");

        string line = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.Length; i++)
        {
            line += "| " + titles[i].PadRight(lengths[i]) + ' ';
        }
        System.Console.WriteLine(line + "|");

        lengths.ForEach(l => System.Console.Write("+-" + new string('-', l) + '-'));
        System.Console.WriteLine("+");

        foreach (var row in rows)
        {
            line = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < row.Length; i++)
            {
                if (int.TryParse(row[i], out int n))
                {
                    line += "| " + row[i].PadLeft(lengths[i]) + ' ';  // numbers are padded to the left
                }
                else
                {
                    line += "| " + row[i].PadRight(lengths[i]) + ' ';
                }
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine(line + "|");
        }

        lengths.ForEach(l => System.Console.Write("+-" + new string('-', l) + '-'));
        System.Console.WriteLine("+");
    }
}
```

Example Result:

[image]